# What does a horizontal line residual plot indicate?

Tags: self-study, residuals

My residuals for 5 data points are 3,3,3,3,4. I'm not sure if this counts as a "pattern" in which case the function should not be a good fit for my data set, in my understanding.

Comment: These can't possibly be all the residuals because residuals have a property that they must sum to zero.  But since $3+3+3+3+5 \ne 0 \implies$ not residuals.

Perhaps you can supply the original data and your model and it's output and we can help you further once you've clarified your question.

Comment: @StatsStudent I'm sorry, I don't know much about this topic but I'm trying to solve a problem where they gave me x and y values and I'm supposed to determine if a function is a good model for the data given. Here are the values.

x = -4,-2,0,2,4
y = -18,-10,-2,6,15
f(x) = 4x-5

Comment: hint: would changing the constant term (-5) help this function to be a better fit?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Well, I think so. So does that mean that it's not a good model for the my data?

Comment: @StatsStudent I do think that f(x)=4x-5 is not a good fit for the given data. The problem specified that I should use residuals to determine whether or not it is (the function was given in the problem). However, I'm not sure if my judgment is correct since I'm not that familiar with residuals but yes, I think that it could be improved upon. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you are right.  One argument I would make is that the model can be improved upon by using a linear regression.  For example, if you look at my answer below, it achieves a better fit than the model in the problem.  And we know that the linear regression model minimizes the errors.  So it depends on what  you mean by "not" good.  It can certainly be improved upon.  If you found my answer helpful, please accept it and upvote it to encourage others to provide answer on this site.  Thank you!

Comment: I've upvoted  your answer. Thank you so much for the help. @StatsStudent

Answer (score 1):

OK. Given your comments, I'll offer this hint:

Have you plotted the raw data first?  With so few data points, you probably don't even need to look at residuals.  I'd encourage you to plot your points $(x,y)$ and overlay a fitted regression line.  It's not clear to me where you obtained your function from since it doesn't appear to be a best fit line from a regression model.  You can try do this with the following code in `R` (you never told us if you are using a program or doing this by hand, by the way, so I'll assume you are using `R`):

```
x = c(-4,-2,0,2,4)
y = c(-18,-10,-2,6,15)
fit1<-lm(y~x)
summary(fit1)
plot(x,y, ylim=c(-20, 20))
abline(fit1, col="blue")
```

Which outputs the following text and graphic:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         5 
 2.00e-01  9.18e-15 -2.00e-01 -4.00e-01  4.00e-01 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.80000    0.16330  -11.02   0.0016 ** 
x            4.10000    0.05774   71.01 6.15e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3651 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9994,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9992 
F-statistic:  5043 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 6.154e-06
```

[image]

Compare your function $f(x)=4x-5$ with the regression model function.  What do you think?  Do you think your function could be improved upon?